# normalize value having large range in r?

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` like the below and the value of each item has values ranging from 14 to 22258.

```
 summary(network_df)

   CUST_ID       SUB_CUST_ID    
 Min.   :   14   Min.   :   14  
 1st Qu.: 5954   1st Qu.: 5954  
 Median :12044   Median :11819  
 Mean   :11641   Mean   :11622  
 3rd Qu.:16955   3rd Qu.:16955  
 Max.   :22258   Max.   :22258
```

But the each column size are 426.

```
str(network_df)

'data.frame':   426 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ CUST_ID       : int  21564 20672 1342 19239 1649 15039 15963 10455 12657 12921 ...
 $ SUB_CUST_ID   : int  20967 6462 12929 18556 13961 13961 5767 15377 17146 19488 ...
```

My question is to make the range of two columns from 1 to 426. Also I want to have a mapping table between original values and converted values.

Is there any good packages for this in `R`?

Comment: Have you looked at the `rank` function? `?rank()`

Comment: Reproducible example, Expected output, Code that you tried and failed. Also note that package recommendation questions are off topic.

Comment: @bouncyball Thanks. The function would be good. I will try! Thanks.

Comment: If those values are just id, and not meaningful, you are looking for `factor`s. See `?factor`.

Comment: @nicola ok, but I have to make an adjacent matrix with converted value. Thanks for your answer!